# npm link not working for one of four local packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-link

I have 4 packages in my package.json:

```json
    "@CT/package-1": "*",
    "@CT/package-2": "*",
    "@CT/package-3": "*",
    "@CT/package-4": "*",
```

All four packages are not on the NPM registry, but locally linked.

In each package directory I did:

```bash
sudo npm link
```

After that I went into my main project and linked all packages like so:

```
npm link @CT/package-1
npm link @CT/package-2
npm link @CT/package-3
npm link @CT/package-4
```

For each command it outputs the linked chain of the sym-links, I checked the paths of each one, and it's correct. If I go in the node_modules folder of my main project and follow `@CT/package-X` I will end up in my local package directory.

Now I expect that I can run `npm i` on my main project and it won't try to install those packages from the npm registry. This works for package 2-4, but it does not work for package-1:

> npm ERR! code E404
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@CT%2fpackage-1 - npm package "package-1" does not exist under owner "CT"

As soon as I remove `"@CT/package-1": "*",` from my package.json, `npm i` will success, because it seems to right-fully skip package 2-4, just not package-1.

Now I inspected all four package projects, and it makes no sense to me. All projects compile, all package.json contain the correct package name. Here is the package.json of my first faulty package:

```json
{
  "name": "@CT/package-1",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/plugin.cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "types": "dist/esm/index.d.ts",
  "unpkg": "dist/plugin.js",
  "files": [
    "android/src/main/",
    "android/build.gradle",
    "dist/"
  ],
  "author": "martin-braun",
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [
    "capacitor",
    "plugin",
    "native"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "npm run prettier -- --check",
    "prettier": "prettier \"**/*.{css,html,ts,js,java}\"",
    "build": "npm run prettier && npm run clean && tsc && rollup -c rollup.config.js",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.0.0",
    "@capacitor/docgen": "^0.0.18",
    "@ionic/eslint-config": "^0.3.0",
    "@ionic/prettier-config": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "prettier": "~2.2.0",
    "prettier-plugin-java": "~1.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^2.32.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.3"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "prettier": "@ionic/prettier-config",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "@ionic/eslint-config/recommended"
  },
  "capacitor": {
    "android": {
      "src": "android"
    }
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/CT"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

.npmrc

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/@CT
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

When I linked the project on my main project it shew the right paths (i.e.)

```
/Users/mb/Projects/CT/MAIN/node_modules/@CT/package-1 -> /Users/mb/node_module_collections/ekol/lib/node_modules/@CT/package-1 -> /Users/mb/Projects/CT/package-1
```

What could I try to find the issue? Again, package 2-4 won't cause `npm i` to fail, but package.json and npmrc look similar. I'm thankful for any advice.

node v13.12.0